# Need to close topic element by using the header title

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having four header named called h1, h2, h3 and h4, I want each one needs to comes under different styles as per DTD

XML Input is:

```
<Segments>
<Segment>
<Body>
<h1>Introduction:</h1>
<h2>Introductory Paragraph</h2>
<p>The introductory paragraph should also include the thesis statement</p>
<h3>Body — First paragraph:</h3>
<p>The first paragraph of the body should contain the strongest argument</p>
<h4>Conclusion:</h4>
<p>an allusion to the pattern used in the introductory paragraph</p>
<h4>Concluding paragraph:</h4>
<p>On the days you get treatment</p>
</Body>
</Segment>
</Segments>
```

XSL I used as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    doctype-public="urn:pubid:com.doctypes.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic"
    doctype-system="topic.dtd"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="DITA.xsl"</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Body"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Segments">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Segment">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body">        
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
      <topic>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
        <title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </title>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
          <subsection>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
            <title>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </title>
            <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h3">
              <subsection>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
                <title>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </title>
                <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h4">
                  <subsection>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <title>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                    </title>
                    <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
                  </subsection>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
              </subsection>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </subsection>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </topic>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting output as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="DITA.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.doctypes.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Introduction:</title>
   <subsection id="topic_2">
      <title>Introductory Paragraph</title>
      <body>
         <p>The introductory paragraph should also include the thesis statement</p>
         <h3>Body — First paragraph:</h3>
         <p>The first paragraph of the body should contain the strongest argument</p>
         <h4>Conclusion:</h4>
         <p>an allusion to the pattern used in the introductory paragraph</p>
         <h4>Concluding paragraph:</h4>
         <p>On the days you get treatment</p>
      </body>
      <subsection id="topic_">
         <title>The introductory paragraph should also include the thesis statement</title>
         <body/>
      </subsection>
      <subsection id="topic_3">
         <title>Body — First paragraph:</title>
         <body>
            <p>The first paragraph of the body should contain the strongest argument</p>
            <h4>Conclusion:</h4>
            <p>an allusion to the pattern used in the introductory paragraph</p>
            <h4>Concluding paragraph:</h4>
            <p>On the days you get treatment</p>
         </body>
         <subsection id="topic_">
            <title>The first paragraph of the body should contain the strongest argument</title>
            <body/>
         </subsection>
         <subsection id="topic_4">
            <title>Conclusion:</title>
            <body>
               <p>an allusion to the pattern used in the introductory paragraph</p>
            </body>
         </subsection>
         <subsection id="topic_5">
            <title>Concluding paragraph:</title>
            <body>
               <p>On the days you get treatment</p>
            </body>
         </subsection>
      </subsection>
   </subsection>
</topic>
```

Output i want as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="DITA.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.doctypes.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Introduction:</title>
   <subsection id="topic_2">
      <title>Introductory Paragraph</title>
      <body>
         <p>The introductory paragraph should also include the thesis statement</p>
      </body>
      <subsection id="topic_3">
         <title>Body — First paragraph:</title>
         <body>
            <p>The first paragraph of the body should contain the strongest argument</p>
         </body>
         <subsection id="topic_4">
            <title>Conclusion:</title>
            <body>
               <p>an allusion to the pattern used in the introductory paragraph</p>
            </body>
         </subsection>
         <subsection id="topic_5">
            <title>Concluding paragraph:</title>
            <body>
               <p>On the days you get treatment</p>
            </body>
         </subsection>
      </subsection>
   </subsection>
</topic>
```

Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the `for-each-group` uses to check whether the first item is a heading:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    doctype-public="urn:pubid:com.doctypes.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic"
    doctype-system="topic.dtd"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="DITA.xsl"</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Body"/>
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Body">        
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
      <topic>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
        <title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </title>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
          <subsection>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
            <title>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </title>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h3">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::h3">
              <subsection>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
                <title>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </title>

                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h4">
                 <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::h4">
                                        <subsection>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <title>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                    </title>
                    <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
                  </subsection>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>

                </xsl:for-each-group>
              </subsection>                      
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </subsection>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </topic>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/94AbWBF.